# Why does botan ask for a random number generator that it ignores for compatibility?

Tags: c++, compatibility, botan

I am starting to use the **botan** cryptographic library and I ran into an odd function signature:

```
/**
* Load an encrypted key from a data source.
* @param source the data source providing the encoded key
* @param rng ignored for compatability
* @param get_passphrase a function that returns passphrases
* @return loaded private key object
*/
BOTAN_DLL Private_Key* load_key(DataSource& source,
                                RandomNumberGenerator& rng,
                                std::function<std::string ()> get_passphrase);
```

I am wondering why should I pass a `RandomNumberGenerator` to a function that promises to ignore it?

The documentation says that it is for compatibility, but I cannot imagine what type of compatibility they are talking about? If it is backwards/forwards compatibility, it means that in the past/future the function has/will accept a random number generator to do a deterministic operation.

Please, what am I missing here?

Comment: which version of botan are you using?

Comment: @fedepad Version 2.0 with datestamp: 20170106.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that it's meant for backward compatibility, to not change the API for the user and possibly to not break applications.
Let's start to have a look at the master branch:
https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/pubkey/pkcs8.cpp

```
/*
* Extract an encrypted private key and return it
*/
Private_Key* load_key(DataSource& source,
                      RandomNumberGenerator& rng,
                      std::function<std::string ()> get_pass)
   {
   return load_key(source, rng, get_pass, true);
   }
```

calls

```
/*
* Extract a private key (encrypted/unencrypted) and return it
*/
Private_Key* load_key(DataSource& source,
                      RandomNumberGenerator& /*rng*/,
                      std::function<std::string ()> get_pass,
                      bool is_encrypted)
   {
   AlgorithmIdentifier alg_id;
   secure_vector<uint8_t> pkcs8_key = PKCS8_decode(source, get_pass, alg_id, is_encrypted);

   const std::string alg_name = OIDS::lookup(alg_id.oid);
   if(alg_name.empty() || alg_name == alg_id.oid.as_string())
      throw PKCS8_Exception("Unknown algorithm OID: " +
                            alg_id.oid.as_string());

   return load_private_key(alg_id, pkcs8_key).release();
   }

}
```

to do the work, which in turn doesn't use `rng`.
Now, let's see previous versions of the library. Same happens for version 2.0.0 (https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/pubkey/pkcs8.cpp)
In version (tag in GitHub) 1.11.33 (https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/1.11.33/src/lib/pubkey/pkcs8.cpp)  one can see that `rng` is used  and it looks that versions after this one dropped it:

```
/*
* Extract a private key (encrypted/unencrypted) and return it
*/
Private_Key* load_key(DataSource& source,
                      RandomNumberGenerator& rng,
                      std::function<std::string ()> get_pass,
                      bool is_encrypted)
   {
   AlgorithmIdentifier alg_id;
   secure_vector<byte> pkcs8_key = PKCS8_decode(source, get_pass, alg_id, is_encrypted);

   const std::string alg_name = OIDS::lookup(alg_id.oid);
   if(alg_name.empty() || alg_name == alg_id.oid.as_string())
      throw PKCS8_Exception("Unknown algorithm OID: " +
                            alg_id.oid.as_string());

   return load_private_key(alg_id, pkcs8_key, rng).release();
   }

}
```

in

```
load_private_key(alg_id, pkcs8_key, rng).release();
```

which seems to be defined in https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/1.11.33/src/lib/pubkey/pk_algs.cpp and starts with

```
std::unique_ptr<Private_Key>
load_private_key(const AlgorithmIdentifier& alg_id,
                 const secure_vector<byte>& key_bits,
                 RandomNumberGenerator& rng)
   {
   const std::string alg_name = OIDS::lookup(alg_id.oid);
   if(alg_name == "")
      throw Decoding_Error("Unknown algorithm OID: " + alg_id.oid.as_string());

#if defined(BOTAN_HAS_RSA)
   if(alg_name == "RSA")
      return std::unique_ptr<Private_Key>(new RSA_PrivateKey(alg_id, key_bits, rng));
#endif

#if defined(BOTAN_HAS_CURVE_25519)
   if(alg_name == "Curve25519")
      return std::unique_ptr<Private_Key>(new Curve25519_PrivateKey(alg_id, key_bits, rng));
#endif
```

Now, if you compare it with master branch or version 2.0.0, you can see that `rng` was dropped from the same calls

https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/pubkey/pk_algs.cpp

```
std::unique_ptr<Private_Key>
load_private_key(const AlgorithmIdentifier& alg_id,
                 const secure_vector<uint8_t>& key_bits)
   {
   const std::string alg_name = OIDS::lookup(alg_id.oid);
   if(alg_name == "")
      throw Decoding_Error("Unknown algorithm OID: " + alg_id.oid.as_string());

#if defined(BOTAN_HAS_RSA)
   if(alg_name == "RSA")
      return std::unique_ptr<Private_Key>(new RSA_PrivateKey(alg_id, key_bits));
#endif
```

In the version that you are using it looks they dropped it too and you have similar to the one in master:

```
std::unique_ptr<Private_Key>
load_private_key(const AlgorithmIdentifier& alg_id,
                 const secure_vector<uint8_t>& key_bits)
   {
   const std::string alg_name = OIDS::lookup(alg_id.oid);
   if(alg_name == "")
      throw Decoding_Error("Unknown algorithm OID: " + alg_id.oid.as_string());

#if defined(BOTAN_HAS_RSA)
   if(alg_name == "RSA")
      return std::unique_ptr<Private_Key>(new RSA_PrivateKey(alg_id, key_bits));
#endif
```

So it looks that to maintain the same API for the user they didn't change the signature but they changed the implementation.